# Segmentation fault assembler

Tags: assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, calling-convention

When I run my program I have segmentation fault error. I don't understand why.

```
   .data
    str1: .string "hello"
    str2: .string "world"
.text
.globl _start
_start:
    pushl $str1
    call puts
    call strcall
    call finish

strcall:
    pushl $str2
    call puts
    ret
finish:
    movl $1, %eax
    movl $0, %ebx
    int $0x80
```

Any idea why is it happening like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal `cdecl` calling convention mandates that the caller remove the arguments it has placed on the stack. Since you don't do that in `strcall`, the `pushl $str2` is still on the stack and `ret` will try to use that as the return address. Solution: insert `addl $4, %esp` before the `ret`.

Next time use a debugger to see where the problem is for yourself.

Also, if you intend to use C library functions, you should really use `main` as entry point and compile with `gcc` so you get the C library properly initialized. Similarly, you should not use the `exit` system call, you should just return from `main` or if abolsutely necessary, `call exit` from the C library.